# How to kill all processes of a Python program?

Tags: python, process, pid, kill-process, sigkill

I am running a Python program service_host.py, which started multiple processes. And when I use `ps -ef | grep python`

to check the pids, it shows a lot:

```
congmin  26968 22897  0 Jun20 ?        00:00:00 python service_host.py
congmin  26969 22897  0 Jun20 ?        00:00:00 python service_host.py
congmin  26970 22897  0 Jun20 ?        00:00:00 python service_host.py
congmin  26971 22897  0 Jun20 ?        00:00:00 python service_host.py
congmin  26972 22897  0 Jun20 ?        00:00:00 python service_host.py
congmin  26973 22897  0 Jun20 ?        00:00:00 python service_host.py
congmin  26974 22897  0 Jun20 ?        00:00:00 python service_host.py
congmin  26975 22897  0 Jun20 ?        00:00:00 python service_host.py
```

What's the best way to kill all these processes at once? I am on Linux and don't want to kill one by one through the process ID. Is there a way to kill them by the Python name 'service_host.py'? I tried this but it didn't kill at all:

```
import psutil

PROCNAME = "service_host.py"

for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    # check whether the process name matches
    if proc.name() == PROCNAME:
        proc.kill()
```

Is there a terminal command that can do this job easily?

Comment: in shell `pkill python` ?

Comment: I dont' want to kill all python processes. only those associated with the name 'service_host.py'

Comment: then try `pkill service_host.py` or maybe `pkill -e 'python service_host.py'`

Comment: No, it doesn't kill at all.

Comment: pkill -f 'service_host.py'. This does the job. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`htop`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/htop) instead you’ll be able to filter with `F4` the processes `service_host` instead and have a look at the whole tree with `F5`. From there you can `kill` them all at once with `F9` ...

Follow these simple 3 steps:

1. enter `htop`

   - *optionally* press `F4` and type `service_host` to filter the process to kill
   - *optionally* press `F5` to sort processes as a tree. This organizes child processes to its primary process ID (PID)
2. scroll the list and **highlight the process to kill**, then press `F9` for kill options
3. highlight `15 SIGTERM` (signal terminate) to gracefully request to stop the proccess(es) or `9 SIGKILL` (signal kill) to forcefully shut down the process(es) and **finally press enter**

I usually go with `9 SIGKILL` without worrying too much, but it's up to you and what you're doing within your python script!

Comment: Exactly how to do this? htop first, seond, press f4, then press f5?

Comment: Yes, `htop` is like the more familiar `top` command, but is not always there, anyway this is for sure a great opportunity to get it [`sudo apt-get install htop`](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-install-htop-on-ubuntu-linux-using-apt/) then you'll find it very useful in such situation. Anyway, `top` should work as well, look for the process and then press the `k` key to kill that PID, that should be unique for all the child processes ;)

Comment: Anyway, exactly you have to follow [these steps](https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/linux/stop-processes-in-htop/) I just summarised here above, editing my answer.

Answer (score 14):

Linux has command `pkill` to kill by name

```
pkill python
```

exact matching

```
pkill -e 'python service_host.py'
```

check in full name

```
pkill -f 'service_host.py'
```

More in `man pkill`

**BTW:** There is also `pgrep` to get PIDs using names.

Answer (score 4):

You've tagged this with "python" and your script was close to doing the right thing, so here is a fixed version of your script -- use the `cmdline` method to extract the command line as a list:

```
import psutil

PROCNAME = "service_host.py"

for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    # check whether the process name matches
    cmdline = proc.cmdline()
    if len(cmdline) >= 2 and "python" in cmdline[0] and cmdline[1] == PROCNAME:
        # print(proc)
        proc.kill()
```

although various possibilities from the Linux command line are of course possible.

```
kill `ps -ef | grep "python service_host.py" | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'`
```

or whatever...